# if statement byte versus integer

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

I am trying to understand a section of code below (excerpt) related to demonstrating bitwise operators, in particular the `if` statement `((if ((b & t)...)`

The variable `b` is of the byte type and the `t` int. I cannot determine how two different variable types are tested to not equal 0 in the loop. The program just goes on to flip the bits. However, I cannot get past this issue. It runs fine in Eclipse. Any ideas?

```
class NotDemo {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        byte b = -34; 
        for (int t=128; t > 0; t = t/2 ) {
            if((b & t) != 0) System.out.print("1 ");
            else System.out.print("0 ");
```

Comment: Java *implicitly converts* `byte` to `int`. It will do `byte` to `short`, `short` to `int`, `int` to `long`,  `char` to `int` (!), `int` to `float`(!), `float` to `double` and the transitive closure of those.

Comment: And `long` to `double` (!). (Those marked with (!) are probably a bad idea even if you like implicit conversions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b & t` performs bit-wise AND on two `int`s. The `byte` `b` is promoted to an `int`.

It prints the bits of the binary representation of `-34`.

The binary representation of -34 is 11011110.

`t` gets the values 128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1, which in binary are

```
10000000
01000000
00100000
00010000
00001000
00000100
00000010
00000001
```

When you bit-wise AND these values of `t` with `b`, you get a non 0 result only when `t` and `b` have a '1' bit in the same position.

```
10000000 & 11011110 = 10000000 -> 1 printed
01000000 & 11011110 = 01000000 -> 1 printed
00100000 & 11011110 = 00000000 -> 0 printed
00010000 & 11011110 = 00010000 -> 1 printed
00001000 & 11011110 = 00001000 -> 1 printed
00000100 & 11011110 = 00000100 -> 1 printed
00000010 & 11011110 = 00000010 -> 1 printed
00000001 & 11011110 = 00000000 -> 0 printed
```

EDIT: this explanation is not completely accurate. The bit-wise AND is performed on two `int`s (i.e. two 32 bit numbers), but since the top 24 bits of `t` are `0`, they don't affect the result.